# Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently working on a small SQL Query, but I'm getting the below Error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.

Here is the Code:

```
SELECT actor.first_name Vorname,
       actor.last_name  Nachname,
       film.length      Filmlaenge
FROM   actor
       INNER JOIN (film_actor
                   INNER JOIN film
                     ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id)
         ON actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id
ORDER  BY film.length DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Use this script   SELECT actor.first_name Vorname, actor.last_name Nachname, film.length Filmlaenge
FROM actor
INNER JOIN film_actor
ON actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id
INNER JOIN film
ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
ORDER BY film.length DESC
LIMIT 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't nest the joins like that.  Put the `ON` right after the `JOIN`.  The following works in the most recent version of Oracle:

```
SELECT a.first_name Vorname, a.last_name Nachname, f.length as Filmlaenge
FROM actor a INNER JOIN
     film_actor a
     ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id INNER JOIN 
     film f
     ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
ORDER BY f.length DESC
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

In earlier versions, you would do:

```
SELECT fa.*
FROM (SELECT a.first_name Vorname, a.last_name Nachname, f.length as Filmlaenge
      FROM actor a INNER JOIN
           film_actor a
           ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id INNER JOIN 
           film f
           ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
      ORDER BY f.length DESC
     ) fa
WHERE rownum <= 10;
```